# i want int in my textbox and in my other i want string with "if"

Tags: c#, if-statement, textbox

I'm new using c#

So in my textbox postal code. I want that i only can use int (1,2,3,4,...) and it may only be 4 numbers. How can i do that?

And what happens with that when you need to fill in your birthday?

And what happens when you fill in a email? (test47@hotmail.com)

So my next question is: In my textbox Name, i want that i only can use string (Paul, Tom, ...). How can i do that?

It must be with an "if". Not with try & catch

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Have you actually *tried* anything? Your question is also unclear about what you expect/started with. Please review the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this is quite easy and to do this you can attack this in many different ways. you can for starters show the code you have tired.. 2nd you can look up how to use Linq, or Lambda, or char.IsDigit function.. read up on some basic C# Tutorials online there are tons of free examples online as well as YouTube and other videos.. also state if this is C# Win Forms or Web Forms app.. `It must be with an "if". Not with try & catch` start coding something yourself first ..this is not a code factory site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in XAML, use InputScope

```
<TextBox InputScope="Number" Name="postalCode" />
```

Comment: not really going to help the OP since XAML is more difficult to understand for the OP than simple asp.net code behind.. also i do not think that he's even doing xaml.. looks more like c# forms by looking at the tags..